# A peculiar kind of prototypal inheritance in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I was reading about the functionality of internal [[Prototype]] chain. So, what does [[Prototype]] do? Actually it is a linker between the objects in objects chain. When we are instantiating an object using "new" keyword or Object.create() function, actually javascript links the [[Prototype]] of that object to another object.

So, I started to implement some codes to understand this more in depth.
I started creating a function and using it as a class.

```
var dad= function(){};
dad.prototype.bloodGroup="O+";
```

Then I added a child class as below :

```
var child= function(){}
child=dad.prototype;
child.name="John";
```

In the next step, I added another child called "anotherChild"

```
var anotherChild= function(){};
anotherChild= dad.prototype;
```

But the mind blowing part was when I called anotherChild object. It was shown as below :

```
>    anotherChild
>    Object { bloodGroup="O+",  name="John"}  !!
```

So this means, However **"anotherChild"** was inherited from "**dad**", but it gets some properties related to another child like **name="John"** but this isn't logical.

Can anybody say why this happens and how **Prototype** and internal **[[Prototype]]** property works here link objects?

Comment: `child = dad.prototype;` overrides the previous value (`function() {}`) with `dad.prototype`. `child.name = ...` later is equivalent to `dad.prototype.name = ...`. This has nothing to do with prototypes. Simpler example: `var foo = {}; bar = foo; baz = foo; bar.name = 'bar';` Of course `baz.name` is `"bar"`. If you want to learn about inheritance, you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Peculiar" is the right word because it does not accomplish inheritance at all (in the classic definition).

Each time you assign `dad.prototype` to something, you're just assigning a reference to the exact same object.  Assigning an object in Javascript does NOT make a copy of it.  So, when you modify that object, you are modifying the same object everywhere.

This notion of "inheritance" that you speak of is wrong in pretty much every way.  You don't have separate objects at all.  What you have is multiple variables that all point to the same prototype object.

Correct inheritance would be done like this:

```
var dad = function(){};
dad.prototype.getBloodGroup = function() {
    return bloodGroup="O+";
};

var child = function(){}      // child constructor
child.prototype = new dad();  // get a copy of a dad object to use as the prototype
var baby = new child();       // create new instance of the child object
baby.name = "John";           // assign property on instance
```

Or, using more modern constructs:

```
var child = function(){}
child.prototype = Object.create(dad.prototype);
var baby = new child();
baby.name = "John";
```

Doing it this way will create a new object that is roughly a copy of the dad.prototype and assign that to the child prototype.  This allows the two prototype objects to be modified separately so that adding new methods to the `child.prototype` won't inadvertently modify the `dad.prototype` object also like your method would have.

---

Here's a step-by-step explanation of what your code is doing:

```
var dad = function(){};
```

Define a constructor function called `dad`.  FYI, modern convention would typically use an uppercase first letter for a constructor function.

```
dad.prototype.bloodGroup="O+";
```

Assign a property to the prototype of that function.

```
var child = function(){}
```

Define another constructor function.

```
child = dad.prototype;
```

Make the `child` variable now point to `dad.prototype` so this replaces the previous definition of the `child` constructor function, rendering that earlier statement now pointless.  So, now `child` is just an alias for `dad.prototype`.  Any modification of the `child` variable is also modifying `dad.prototype` because both point at the exact same object.

```
child.name = "John";
```

Adds another property to `dad.prototype`.  This is exactly the same as:

```
dad.prototype.name = "John";
```

So, at this point, `child` is not an object definition at all.  It's just an alias for `dad.prototype`.  You haven't done anything related to inheritance at all.

```
var anotherChild = function(){};
```

Define another constructor function.

```
anotherChild = dad.prototype;
```

Redefine the `anotherChild` variable to now also be an alias for `dad.prototype`.

---

So, then lastly when you type `anotherChild` into the console, that variable just points to `dad.prototype` so what you see in the console is a dump of the contents of `dad.prototype`:

```
>    anotherChild
>    Object { bloodGroup="O+",  name="John"}  !!
```

which is exactly what one would expect.  You have not defined any inheritance or created any instances of objects other than the `dad` constructor and the `dad.prototype`.  Both `child` and `anotherChild` are just aliases for `dad.prototype`.

Your entire code can be distilled down to this:

```
var dad = function(){};              // define constructor function
dad.prototype.bloodGroup = "O+";     // add property to dad.prototype
var child = dad.prototype;           // create alias to dad.prototype
dad.prototype = "John";              // add property to dad.prototype
var anotherChild = dad.prototype;    // create another alias to dad.prototype
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct way of doing prototypical inheritance is not like

```
child = dad.prototype; // bad
```

But it's done like this

```
child.prototype = new dad(); // good
```

---

## The actual answer:

When you do `child = dad.prototype`, `child` is now `dad`'s `prototype` so when you do `child.name = "John"`, you're essentially doing:

```
dad.prototype.name = "John";
```

So the property reflects on the all the instances of `dad`, but that's not the reason why you get such output for `anotherChild` as it is essentially the `dad.prototype` on which `name` property was just added.

The fix? Do it in the correct way as stated in the first part of this answer.

Comment: Your inheritance example doesn't make a lot of sense though. Why does the function need to be named "John"?

Comment: `child.name = "John";` does not look correct.  That line of code looks like it's giving a particular instance a name property, but that is not what that line of code does.  Instead, it makes a property on the constructor.

Comment: But if you write :  child.prototype = new dad(); // good
child.name = "John";    and then call child.name, the result will be an empty string!!

Answer (score 0):

The assignment:

```
child=dad.prototype;
```

causes both `child` and `dad.prototype` to refer to the same object.  And so,

```
child.name = "John";
```

is equivalent to:

```
dad.prototype.name = "John";
```

That is the reason `anotherChild` appeared to get properties from the `child` object.